# NSIS: call MUI_PAGE_LICENSE from function but get "XPStyle not valid" error

Tags: nsis

I have a custom dialog with an "License terms and conditions." checkbox where the Text to the checkbox is actually a link which is suppose to show the License Dialog.

```
; === LicenseLink (type: Link) ===
${NSD_CreateLink} 132.96u 100.92u 107.29u 14.15u "License terms and conditions."
Pop $hCtl_welcome_LicenseLink
${NSD_OnClick} $hCtl_welcome_LicenseLink ShowLicense
```

Now in the function "ShowLicense" I tried calling

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE
```

but get an error:
Error: command XPStyle not valid in Function

evidently I'm approaching this wrong and I can't interpret the error. Would be happy for any ideas on how to resolve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to create a single "input" page + the instfiles page installer?

Comment: @Anders - I hope I understand your question correct: but yes, I'm trying to create a page with the Installpath and a "Agree to License Terms" on the same page. The user would then just have to click install and be done with the installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call `!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE` dynamically, the number of pages is determined at compile time.

You can however skip pages to achieve this:

```
InstallDir "$Temp\Test"

!include MUI2.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE SkipLicensePage
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${__FILE__}"
Page Custom InfoPageCreate InfoPageValidate
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English


Var ShowLicensePage
Function SkipLicensePage
${IfThen} $ShowLicensePage = 0 ${|} Abort ${|} ; Skip it the first time
FunctionEnd

Function OnShowLicense
SendMessage $hWndParent ${WM_COMMAND} 3 "" ; Click the (hidden) back button
FunctionEnd

Var InstDirCtl
Function InfoPageCreate
StrCpy $ShowLicensePage 1
GetDlgItem $0 $hWndParent 3
ShowWindow $0 0 ; Hide the back button
!insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Blah blah" "blah blah blah"
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateText} 0 13u 100% 12u "$InstDir"
Pop $InstDirCtl

${NSD_CreateLink} 2u 40u -4u 12u "License"
Pop $0
${NSD_OnClick} $0 OnShowLicense

nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function InfoPageValidate
${NSD_GetText} $InstDirCtl $InstDir
FunctionEnd
```